# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined (angular-fontawesome)

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to use fontawesome in my Angular project. I would like to try out [FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome), but I get an error in the browser console, if I try to use an icon:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined
    at FaIconComponent.ngOnChanges (webpack-internal:///../../../../@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome.es5.js:112)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12576)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14104)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14047)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14940)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14881)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.ngfactory.js:154)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14866)
    at checkAndUpdateView (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14013)
    at callViewAction (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14364)
```

I installed `@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome` and the two dependencies (`@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid` and `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands`) with `npm`

I imported it in the `app.module.ts`, and added it to the `imports`:

```
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
```

Did I miss something during the installation? I get no error on the terminal when I start the application using `ng serve --open`, I only get the error in the browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same error, only to realize that I had template values that didn't match the component names.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <fa-icon [icon]="caretLeft"></fa-icon>
</button>
```

When in my component, I had

```
private faCaretLeft = faCaretLeft;
```

It was a rookie mistake that stemmed from some renaming I did trying to troubleshoot previous errors.  When I changed the icon binding to the correct name, the error was resolved.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
  <fa-icon [icon]="faCaretLeft"></fa-icon>
</button>
```